# Yosemite and Valgrind

Tags: macos, valgrind, osx-yosemite

Can you tell me how to install valgrind on yosemite? When I try to install it i get " checking for the kernel version... unsupported (14.0.0)
configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 10.x, 11.x, 12.x and 13.x (Mac OS X 10.6/7/8/9) "

There is no official path or update, and I didn't found anything (except http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.kde.devel.bugs/1553705 , but they didn't resolve that problem).

Comment: [Known issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29988) with `homebrew` with an unsympathetic note: _" Unlikely to be fixed in the near future due to upstream's development timetable"_

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thank you, I have solved this problem for some time by installing Ubuntu on virtual machine and then install valgrind on Ubuntu

Answer (score 286, accepted):

As there's no stable release that supports Yosemite, you can install the latest development version with

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```

Comment: This command no longer works.  I get this message: `Error: Failed to download resource "valgrind--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/cd26a902d72aabd0b51d/raw/1a61a328a87a728dccbeef0594f6fe335e9bf917/valgrind-sdk-paths-Makefile-am.diff`

Comment: Whilst this was the correct resolution at the time of posting, Valgrind now supports OS X Yosemite through the application's documented release channels.

Answer (score 50):

Whilst it may have been the case in past OS X release cycles that Valgrind took a period of time before achieving reasonable feature support, basic OS X 10.10 support is already available in Valgrind trunk due to significant work on pre-release Yosemite.

From the mailing list:

> There has been some effort recently to improve Valgrind's support for
>   Yosemite.  If you develop on Mac OS, you might like to try out the
>   trunk (svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk) and report any
>   breakage you get.  Support for Yosemite is good enough that at least
>   one large graphical application (Firefox) runs OK.  Support for the
>   previous release, 10.9 (Mavericks), is also substantially improved.
>
> Note that the work has targetted 64 bit processes only.  32 bit might
>   work, and probably better on Mavericks, but I suspect it will be
>   increasingly problematic on Yosemite due to Valgrind's 32 bit x86
>   instruction set support not having progressed passed SSSE3.
>
> Julian Seward

http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/33047840/

*Full disclosure: I'm one of the new Valgrind developers who contributed patches to support OS X 10.10*

Comment: +1 for contributing to valgrind. Ran it against my code. It pointed out the cause of a segmentation fault that has been driving me crazy for the past 24 hours since I couldn't find the cause.

Answer (score 11):

Valerio's svn workflow will download every branch which is time and resource consuming.  A better procedure is to download just the trunk:

```
svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
cd valgrind
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Noticing that downloading this takes far longer than the release source .tar.bz did... is it just the compression that makes such a big difference or is it actually downloading files that it wouldn't otherwise? (I guess it could be the different server... or the difference between `svn co` and `curl`...)

Comment: +1: Worked great. Only thing I changed was I did `sudo make install` at the end instead of `make install`. Not sure if it was necessary or not as I didn't try it your way.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my take on it. I more or less had a clean mac with xcode installed.
Got it compiling and running with the following:

```
# build/install autoconf/automake/libtool so that 'autogen' works
curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
tar -xzf autoconf-2.69.tar.gz 
cd autoconf-2.69
./configure && make && sudo make install
cd ..

curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/automake/automake-1.14.tar.gz
tar -xzf automake-1.14.tar.gz
cd automake-1.14
./configure && make && sudo make install
cd..

curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf libtool-2.4.2.tar.gz
cd libtool-2.4.2
./configure && make && sudo make install
cd ..

svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
cd valgrind
./autogen.sh
# important: configure-params, otherwise make ends in errors 
./configure -disable-tls --enable-only64bit --build=amd64-darwin 
make
# sudo, otherwise it fails due to permissions 
sudo make install
```

Note that callgrind_control (from valgrind-3.11.0 SVN) doesn't appear to work on OS X, looks like a perl-script and the commandline tool which it runs (vgdb -l) prints something 'unexpected' which that script doesn't correctly parse ( so it won't be able to find the other process running with valgrind ).

Alternatively, the perl script just calls vgdb, we can also directly do that ( just figure out your process-id manually):

```
vgdb --pid=2858 instrumentation on
```

Comment: Brilliant, this was *exactly* what I need to get valgrind running on Yosemite 10.10.4

Only thing, the command above denoting the -disable-tls switch has a unicode hyphen character, rather than the regular ascii hyphen.

Comment: Happy I could help - thanks for pointing out the hyphen (updated it). Also added a work-around for the callgrind_control problem.

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me on 10.10.1 :

```
svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind
cd valgrind
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Tried this. I gave up while downloading a lot of irrelevant tests.

Comment: The regression tests are an essential part of the Valgrind program from a developer's perspective. Whilst an official Valgrind release is yet to be made with the recent improvements to OS X platform support, unfortunately you'll need to download a version with the tests. If for any reason SVN download is troublesome on your connection, then there  are *unofficial* GitHub repositories: https://github.com/liquid-mirror/valgrind

Answer (score 6):

All of the solutions listed here failed for me.  What finally ended up working was to use mac ports.

`sudo port install valgrind-devel`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to install it using alternative sources besides the official svn (because it seems to be intermittently available).

https://crispyappstudiosblog.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/installing-valgrind-on-osx-yosemite/

> 1) Navigate to this git mirror of the svn and download the latest
>   available version: `http://repo.or.cz/w/valgrind.git`
>
> 2) You need VEX as well, so grab the latest version here:
>   `http://repo.or.cz/w/vex.git`
>
> 3) Extract both of them.  Put the entire contents of the `VEX` folder
>   into a folder called VEX in the top level of the valgrind directory.
>
> `cd` to the valgrind directory, and execute the following:
>
> ```
> Run ./autogen.sh
>
> Run ./configure
>
> Run make
>
> Run sudo make install
> ```
>
> Test it out by running `valgrind --version` You should be running at
>   least 3.11.0 SVN for it work on Yosemite.
>   [image: Valgrind 3.11.0 SVN running on OSX Yosemite 10.10.4]

Answer (score 3):

I installed it on my mac by installing `homebrew` and then running this 3 commands in the terminal.

1. `brew update`
2. `brew doctor`
3. `brew install --HEAD valgrind`

PS: I have Os X El Capitan (10.11) but this should work with previous versions too.

Comment: Anything newer than that gives:
`valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS`
`versions newer than El Capitan due to an upstream incompatibility.`

Answer (score 2):

I finally got **Valgrind** to work on my **OSX El Capitan 10.11.12**.

User **Kalmiya**'s answer worked for me first after I installed Xcode commandline tools.

Type this in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Now follow **Kalmiya**'s post, step by step.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30366798/3633475

Comment: my mac book pro has latest version of mac os already updated and it is 10.11.3 not 10.11.12! also your suggestion not worked for me. this is error `Assertion 'tst->os_state.pthread - magic_delta == self' failed.`

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi The "Assertion 'test->os_state.pthread - magic_delta == self'" error has been fixed for Valgrind in the SVN development version.

Comment: @RhysKidd Thanks a lot for info :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take on the svn install. The previous ones did not work for me, since I needed to have `automake` and `autoconf` installed, which I did not, even though I had the latest version of the Xcode command line tools installed.

I got the following from [this site](http://ranf.tl/2014/11/28/valgrind-on-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite/). I also had to link `automake` and `autoconf` after doing `brew install automake` and `brew install autoconf` by doing `brew link automake` and `brew link autoconf` for this to work.

```
# Check out their repo...
$ svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind-trunk
# and hop into it.
$ cd valgrind-trunk

# You need to have autoconf and automake installed to build Valgrind
# This example uses Homebrew to install these dependencies
# (MacPorts should also work)
# (Permission error? add sudo!)
$ brew install automake
$ brew install autoconf

# run autogen.sh in valgrind-trunk
$ ./autogen.sh

# Tricky, there are some hard wired paths in the Valgrind sources.
# You need to symlink the mach folder in your XCode SDK to /usr/include/mach
# Be sure to use the proper Xcode SDK "MacOSX10.10.sdk" in the path!
$ ln -sv /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/mach /usr/include/mach

# Run configure + set install paths in valgrind-trunk
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local

# Run Make and make install (permission error? add sudo!) in valgrind-trunk
$ make
$ make install

# Check it works
$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.11.0.SVN
```

Comment: On 10.10.3 still no success:
`$ make
...
Making all in coregrind
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs', needed 'by m_mach/mach_vmUser.c'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
`
although the /usr/include/mach was created under root, symlinked as described etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have used kalmiya's instructions to build valgrind as a conda package for OSX Yosemite. For those who work with anaconda/conda, just do

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/groakat valgrind
```

Side-note: 
I needed to install the command line tools as described below to get valgrind compiled.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30471647/2156909

Answer (score 0):

I got valgrind on Yosemite compiled, but had to use a hack to do so. While I think you should be using `xcode-select install` to get all command line tools (after which valgrind should make properly), but if you don't want to do this (eg. size of Xcode tools too big), you can also get the Darwin OSX code and copy the following files to `/usr/include/mach`

```
   mach_vm.defs
    task.defs
    thread_act.defs
    vm_map.defs
```

This allowed a clean compile and install, although note it is a rather slack hack.