# Is there an alternative to Valgrind on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, valgrind, osx-yosemite

Now that we OS X Yosemite is out, we have the same problem as always ... Valgrind doesn't work on OS X 10.10.

Is there a working alternative to Valgrind, that can find memory leaks and other kinds of memory errors, like Valgrind does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27408219), Valgrind is available for Yosemite, but only from trunk.
Use

`brew install valgrind --HEAD`

to install.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that Valgrind is still a bit unstable on Mac in certain situations. If you're only looking for identifying (definite) memory leaks you could give [Heapusage](https://github.com/d99kris/heapusage) a try. Its output is similar to Valgrind, so it should be easy to use.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of Heapusage.