# Why is Valgrind saying killed 9 for a very simple program?

Tags: c++, macos, valgrind

I'm running `valgrind` on two very simple 'hello world' programs. They are both returning the same error:

```
laptop$ g++ hello.cpp -o hello 
laptop$ valgrind ./hello
Killed: 9
laptop$ g++ hello2.cpp -o hello2
laptop$ valgrind ./hello2 
Killed: 9
```

My hello2.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("main.c\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The other hello world program simply uses `cout` from `iostream` instead of `printf()`. One important thing to note is that valgrind works as expected on Ubuntu server 14.04, and these failing examples are on my new Macbook Pro running OSX 10.10. I've searched around and everything I find is relating to large programs with complex memory issues.

Why am I getting this error on my Mac?

Comment: Probably because Valgrind doesn't support 10.10 yet.

Comment: Valgrind support on MAC OSX is very bad in general.

Comment: Did you get Valgrind via these instructions? http://ranf.tl/2014/11/28/valgrind-on-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite/

Comment: I used a package installer (not sure which one), but doing it from source with those instructions worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a package manager (such as `apt-get`) to install `valgrind` on OSX 10.10 is unreliable. Download and build from source using the following link:

http://ranf.tl/2014/11/28/valgrind-on-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite/

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it may have been the case in past OS X release cycles that Valgrind took a period of time before achieving reasonable feature support, basic OS X 10.10 and OSX 10.11 support is already available in Valgrind trunk due to significant recent work.

From the mailing list:

> There has been some effort recently to improve Valgrind's support for
>   Yosemite. If you develop on Mac OS, you might like to try out the
>   trunk (svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk) and report any
>   breakage you get. Support for Yosemite is good enough that at least
>   one large graphical application (Firefox) runs OK. Support for the
>   previous release, 10.9 (Mavericks), is also substantially improved.
>
> Note that the work has targetted 64 bit processes only. 32 bit might
>   work, and probably better on Mavericks, but I suspect it will be
>   increasingly problematic on Yosemite due to Valgrind's 32 bit x86
>   instruction set support not having progressed passed SSSE3.
>
> Julian Seward

http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/33047840/

*Full disclosure: I'm one of the new Valgrind developers who contributed patches to support OS X 10.10 and OS X 10.11*

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27408219/388010). Short version:

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```