# how to fix "malloc: can't protect region for postlude guard page" warnings on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, malloc

I'm developing an iOS app and when I run it on my devices I got lots of the following warnings:

MyApp(2138,0x104338000) malloc: *** can't protect(0x3) region for postlude guard page at 0x104950000

They don't stop the execution but looks scary and probably are related to occasional crash of my app. I googled and only found two pages on the entire web and none of the helps. I wonder if anyone here knows how to fix this?

**Edit**: here is the product scheme I used: 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The error you're seeing comes from [Apple's malloc implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-391.4.2/gen/scalable_malloc.c?txt) and is due to `vm_protect` failing when trying modify memory protection of the guard pages that have been added to your memory allocations.

So it sounds like you've enabled `debugmalloc`'s `MallocGuardEdges` flag (I didn't think `debugmalloc` was available on ios devices).

The `0x3` = [`VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE`](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/vm_protect.html) in the message is saying that `vm_protect` failed to make the page read-write which means that this is happening in response to a `free`.

The only documented [`return codes for vm_protect`](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/vm_protect.html) are `KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE` and `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` so at this point I can only guess what happened. Making a page read-write seems like a modest request, for a valid page you wouldn't expect `KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE`, which leaves `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`, meaning that perhaps your page at `0x104950000` is invalid.

Which would imply a memory stomping bug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the thorough answer. I wonder if there is any tool like valgrind that can give more detail on the memory stomping bug? or is there any good tutorials on how to track it manually?

Comment: Apparently dev valgrind works on osx yosemite! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564125/yosemite-and-valgrind

Answer (score 1):

The issue is one-year old, but we ran into the same issue and found this thread. We where able to simplify and reproduce it in latest Xcode 7.3 on Mac with the following piece of C code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    const int s = 100, n = 5000;
    int i;
    void *p = malloc(s);
    for (i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++)
        p = realloc(p,i * s);
    for (i = n - 1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
        void *newp = realloc(p,i * s);
        if (newp != p)
            printf("realloc(p,%d * %d = %d) changes pointer from %p to %p\n",i,s,i * s,p,newp);
        p = newp;
        }
    free(p);
    return 0;
    }
```

This will trigger the malloc_printf() breakpoint in the 2nd for loop (when the reallocations shrink memory) and print:

```
malloc: *** can't protect(0x3) region for postlude guard page at 0x48ed000
```

It appears (setting a breakpoint on malloc_printf()) that this happens exactly on the first time that realloc() changes the returned pointer, the total output of above program is:

```
realloc(p,1249 * 100 = 124900) changes pointer from 0x48b0000 to 0x5000000
realloc(p,2 * 100 = 200) changes pointer from 0x5000000 to 0x240cc60
```

Playing a bit with combinations of the block size s and number of iterations n it happens at least for 10/50000, 100/5000, 200/5000, ..., it seems when the allocated memory i * s shrinks to around 124000 bytes. Other combinations like 1/200000 don't trigger malloc_printf().

Given the simplicity of this code snippet, we believe that this is a bug in Apple's malloc debug implementation.... or the message is supposed to be some informative (internal) message rather than trying to signal a real memory issue.

(A version of) the source code for Apple's malloc implementation can be found here http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-391.4.2/gen/scalable_malloc.c?txt. We are considering to raise with Apple Developer Centre...

So in short the answer is that it might very well not be a memory stomping bug in your code, but instead an issue in de malloc debug code itself, in which case you need to just ignore the message.