# Error installing valgrind

Tags: macos, valgrind

i try to install valgrind on my mac but when I execute `./autogen.sh` get this error:

```
running: aclocal
./autogen.sh: line 6: aclocal: command not found
error: while running 'aclocal'
```

does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I spent some time trying to install valgrind on Yosemite earlier this week and gave up. I tried the Homebrew and MacPorts installs (latest development versions) and both failed for various reasons. Search StackOverflow for this topic though, as there are already a lot of relevant questions/answers (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564125/yosemite-and-valgrind/27408219#27408219) and at least one SO contributor (@RhysKidd) works on valgrind.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
brew install automake
```

Then you can use aclocal

Answer (score 8):

Two third party tools (autoconf and automake) are required on your system to build and install a development version of Valgrind. These tools are no longer packaged with Apple's Xcode development environment and must be installed manually.

To install these tools, enter the following commands in the Terminal:

```
curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
tar -xzf autoconf-latest.tar.gz 
cd autoconf-[x.xx]
./configure && make && sudo make install

curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/automake/automake-1.15.tar.gz
tar -xzf automake-1.15.tar.gz
cd automake-1.15
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

You will then be able to continue following the steps per: http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html

If you are on OS X, you will want to use a development version of Valgrind at present whilst that platform's support is brought back up to standard.

Answer (score 6):

If you install [brew](http://brew.sh) , then use `brew install automake` and `brew install autoconf`

Answer (score 5):

You don't have autotools installed. If you want to run `autogen.sh` you will have to [install](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/faq/autotools-faq.html#How-do-I-install-the-Autotools-_0028as-user_0029_003f) it first.

But if you just want to install valgrind you don't need to run `autogen.sh`. Download latest source package from [valgrind.org](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html#current), extract it and run `./configure` script.

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

However, if your system is Yosemite, you will probably need latest development version from svn and you will have to install autotools first.

Comment: As of Valgrind 3.11.0 there should be reasonable Yosemite (OS X 10.10) support out of the box.