# Performance/memory analyzing tool for production OSX application on customer site

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix

I need to be able analyzing Performance/memory issues which occurs on customer site for a OSX production application written with Objective-C.

As for now I found:
OSXPmem – it’s main drawback is that I need to dump all memory space to in to a single file(it’s not possible for me to transfer ~4GB or more from customer site - I can zip it but the bigger problem is that it not support 10.10 Yosemite.
Valgrind – Does not support 10.10 Yosemite.

Is there a good tool out there ? (such as WinDBG for windows)

BTW at development I use Instruments but in this case it does not  help.

thanks for the help

Comment: Did you tried zipping the file ? Ram usually compress very well.
What informations are you exactly looking at ?

Comment: I need to find memory leak in my code. so very helpful information would be to know which objects are exists in memory and the count of each type

Comment: Anzi please see my update

Comment: The only solution I can think about is logging this informations...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently valgrind will build, install, and work on osx 10.10 from the head of the development branch in the source repository, e.g. as per [yosemite-and-valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564125/yosemite-and-valgrind) and http://kalapun.com/posts/checking-c-code-with-valgrind-on-yosemite/

However depending on how the application works you may have more luck with the `leaks` command-line tool or the full-fledged Instruments tool, from Xcode.  I haven't upgraded to 10.10 yet to try it there, but it should obviously still work in the latest Xcode for 10.10.  `leaks` attaches to the running process, so is better for long-running processes that you can't shut down (cleanly), or for capturing usage metrics during specific operations.