# Valgrind callgrind on OSX Yosemite

Tags: c++, macos, qt, valgrind

I've installed valgrind on OSX Yosemite using `brew install --HEAD valgrind` and also build as per question [Yosemite and Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564125/yosemite-and-valgrind).

For now I have:

```
$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.11.0.SVN
```

When I'm running memory leak checks it seems to run fine:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --dsymutil=yes ./someapp
..
```

But when I'm trying to profile function calls I get:

```
$ valgrind --tool=callgrind ./someapp
valgrind: Unknown option: --leak-check=full
valgrind: Use --help for more information or consult the user manual.
```

My objective is to run Valgrind Function Profiler in Qt Creator 3.3.2 with Qt 5.4.1 Clang 6.0 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what I wanted but this worked for me:

```
$ sudo valgrind --tool=callgrind ./someapp
```

Not sure if I can give specific rights to account.