# Valgrid v3.12 won't compile

Tags: c, macos, valgrind

I'm trying to compile valgrind so I can use it to test a program I've written, but while compiling I get this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in include
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in VEX
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in coregrind
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs', needed by `m_mach/mach_vmUser.c'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could this be an error in the auto-generated makefiles? Or is it an error in the autoconf scripts written by the maintainers? I don't see how it could be the first one, and if it were the second option then it should be fixed fairly quickly because Valgrind is a prominent software tool?

I'm on Mac OS X 10.12.3.

Comment: Best to use homebrew and not try to build it yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564125/yosemite-and-valgrind

Comment: Note that [valgrind currently has "limited support" for 10.12](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html). I can't make it work at all.