# valgrind mac os sierra 10.12.1

Tags: macos, operating-system, valgrind

Is there any possible ways to install valgrind on new Mac OS?
brew tell

```
brew install -HEAD valgrind
valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
versions newer than El Capitan due to an upstream incompatibility.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

valgrind ls -l
valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 253952) failed in UME (load_segment1) with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).
```

Comment: Nah, it's apparently not yet compatible: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=365327

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valgrind on macOS Sierra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650338/valgrind-on-macos-sierra)

Comment: HI Glement, I also have this problem, the latest version of valgrind does not work, do you have any solutions at this moment?

Comment: virtualbox+linux)

Comment: This is now partially resolved on the master branch of valgrind

Comment: upgrade to valgrind 3.13.0 solves the problem

Answer (score 4):

It seems that people are working on trying to get Valgrind to work on MAC OS X 10.12, the most relevant thread of which can be found here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=365327.

The last post includes a patch to revision 16297, which is supposed to provide at least some basic functionality. The patch can be found here: https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=104964.

Obviously this patch is still very much in development, and the author (Louis Brunner) has stated that it is incomplete, the relevant excerpt being:

> "I have been working on a patch to support macOS Sierra. At the
>   moment, it works for a variety of programs (python, GIMP, most basic
>   commands like ls, mkdir) but it is still incomplete (warnings in dyld,
>   libsystem_kernel... crash for some GUI programs)."

However, if you, like me, are willing to risk an incomplete version, the installation instructions are as follows:

First, install automake and svn, if those are not already installed on your system. After that, you should be able to build and install Valgrind on MAC OS X 10.12 with the following instructions:

```
svn checkout -r 16297 svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk
cd trunk
curl https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=105218 > patch.txt
svn patch patch.txt
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

If it doesn't work for your use-case, the only solution is probably to wait until the kinks have been worked out.

Edit: a newer patch can be found here: https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=105218. I have updated the code above with the new patch. While still showing numerous warnings, valgrind now works with "ls", "ls -l", a simple "hello_world" program, and the program that prompted me to download valgrind in the first place.

Comment: The patch has been updated already to v2, so in stead of the attachment link above, use this one: [https://bugs.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=105218](https://bugs.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=105218)

Comment: Thank you for the new patch, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Valgrind 3.13.0** released on June 14, 2017 (see: [Current Releases](http://valgrind.org/downloads/)) has better support for  {x86,amd64}-darwin (Mac OS X 10.12). I had no problem installing Valgrind 3.13.0 by running

`brew install valgrind`

See [Homebrew Formulas Homebrew project](http://brewformulas.org/Valgrind).

Answer (score 1):

http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html, this a link for current releases of Valgrind. Download the latest one and follow the instruction in the README.txt. You should also know by now that the support is limited for MAC OS X 10.11 and 10.12.