# How can I use Valgrind on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: c, valgrind

How can I get Valgrind working on Mac OS Sierra? I tried installing it but it seems to be incompatible. Or is there an alternative that I can use?

Comment: Please see this thread also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650338/valgrind-on-macos-sierra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valgrind on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650338/valgrind-on-macos-sierra)