# How to install Valgrind on macOS Mojave(10.14) with Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, valgrind, memory-leak-detector

I tried to install Valgrind with `brew install Valgrind` and got  :

```
valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected
on macOS versions newer than Sierra due to an upstream
incompatibility. 
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I tried  `brew install --HEAD Valgrind`.

Instead, after successfully installing the dependencies `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool`, when it tries to install valgrind, I get a configure error:

```
Valgrind works on Darwin 10.x, 11.x, 12.x, 13.x, 14.x, 15.x, 16.x and
17.x (Mac OS X 10.6/7/8/9/10/11 and macOS 10.12/13)
```

My OS is macOS Mojave(10.14), so does it mean that I can't install a functioning Valgrind with Homebrew presently?

Comment: Maybe try `brew edit valgrind` and replace "https://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git" with "git://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git" in head section of the formula.

Comment: I have tried that but it still shows the exact same messages...

Comment: here's the latest status I can find. tl;dr: it's not ready yet. https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg285805.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A (rather painful) install from source workaround based on [this patch](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=399584#c9), [this post](http://www.qingpingshan.com/rjbc/ios/402094.html) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/630675/1001101).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Echelon9/valgrind.git
$ cd valgrind
$ git checkout feature/v3.14/macos-mojave-support-v2
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/where/you/want/it/installed --enable-only64bit
$ make
```

If you get the following error:   `No rule to make target '/usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs’`, you will need to run `xcode-select --install`. You might need to install Xcode from the app store if you don't already have it. Once that's done, you will need to edit the `coregrind/Makefile`:

Search for:

```
am__append_19 = \
    /usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs \
        /usr/include/mach/task.defs \
        /usr/include/mach/thread_act.defs \
        /usr/include/mach/vm_map.defs
```

After double checking the below folder exists, prefix every line with:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
```

End result should be:

```
am__append_19 = \
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs \
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/task.defs \
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/thread_act.defs \
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/vm_map.defs
```

Now run `make` again and the includes should be found. But that doesn't necessarily mean it will compile. I got the following error:

```
vg_preloaded.c:136:19: error: expected ';' before 'const'
 __private_extern__ const char *__crashreporter_info__ = "Instrumented by Valgrind " VERSION;
```

A fix for this is to add the following line:

```
#define __private_extern__ extern
```

to the following files:

- `coregrind/m_syscall.c`
- `coregrind/m_syswrap/syswrap-darwin.c`
- `coregrind/vg_preloaded.c`

Finally, you need to cross your fingers hoping no other errors show up:

```
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: I was able to install the valgrind using the above instructions on MacOS Mojave 10.14.13
without adding a fix to the files: coregrind/m_syscall.c, coregrind/m_syswrap/syswrap-darwin.c, coregrind/vg_preloaded.c

Comment: To add to this, you may have to change "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk" to reflect your sdk version.  In my case it was "MacOSX10.11.sdk".  Therefore in my case the path was "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk".

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Mac OS 10.14.4. I ended up with this error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mach_msg_destroy", referenced from:
      __kernelrpc_mach_vm_allocate in libcoregrind-amd64-darwin.a(libcoregrind_amd64_darwin_a-mach_vmUser.o) .."

Comment: I would like to add that running ./autogen.sh requires the package "automake" to be installed. You can do that via:
brew install automake

Comment: This fails to compile in macOS 10.14.6 with Xcode 11.2.1. I get the error `"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/mach/task.defs", line 509: type 'task_exc_guard_behavior_t' not defined`

Answer (score 31):

You may use Experimental Version of Valgrind for macOS 10.14.5 Mojave at:

https://github.com/sowson/valgrind

The command to use it is:

```
brew install --HEAD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sowson/valgrind/master/valgrind.rb
```

It is still experimental and needs some work but for simple projects works already... Enjoy!

Comment: Today I synced with original valgrind repo with patch and tested with Mojave 10.14.6 the thing is that it works still for simple projects but not for a complex one I have maybe someone join as a contributor to help? :D.

Comment: It says `Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man5`

Answer (score 14):

addition: I found this one worked for me on my OSX 10.14

```
brew install --HEAD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos/master/valgrind.rb
```

A branch that is working to get OSX correct. something to tide us over until we get a real valgrind version fixed.

Comment: This sadly now fails to build on macOS 10.14.6 with Xcode 11.2.1.

Answer (score 11):

As others have mentioned, Louis Brunner maintains a working version at https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos.

```sh
brew tap LouisBrunner/valgrind
brew install --HEAD LouisBrunner/valgrind/valgrind
```

This worked for me for MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina.

Answer (score 9):

I am having the same issue. It seems like valgrind is not compatible with the newest macOS(10.14 Mojave). Tried installing it the High Sierra way (https://www.gungorbudak.com/blog/2018/04/28/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-high-sierra/) and got the same output you described. The only solution I can offer you right now is either working on virtual machine (https://www.virtualbox.org/) or using Docker (https://www.gungorbudak.com/blog/2018/06/13/memory-leak-testing-with-valgrind-on-macos-using-docker-containers/).

Answer (score 6):

I have just found a working solution to use VALGRIND on my Mac (Mojave 10.14.6). Just run this command :

```
brew install --HEAD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos/master/valgrind.rb
```

(From https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos)

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Not a proper solution for macOs, but for the time being, I created a docker image. After installing docker for macOS, this is how to start valgrind:

```
cd </path/to/source/directory/where/you/want/run/valgrind/with>
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biocyberman/ValgrindDocker/master/startValgrind
./startValgrind # this will takes time for the first time, because it needs to fetch docker valgrind image
# you will get a root command prompt inside the docker image. 
# do what ever you want
# type 'exit' to quit
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019-NOV-30, it is possible to *build* against OS X 10.14.6 via https://github.com/sowson/valgrind and https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos

*However*, there are many test failures (see the LouisBrunner link), noise during runs, and SEGVs when running against non-trivial programs: *installing* is, well, installing. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this specific version of OSX is problematic with valgrind, so it won't be easy as `brew install` the package. Fortunately the following way worked for me:

**First download need MacOSX10.14 sdk**, This comes with XCode but you can also download it [here](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases). The path where you unzip it will be referenced as `<PATH TO OSX SDK>`

Then do the following

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Echelon9/valgrind.git
$ cd valgrind
$ git checkout feature/v3.14/macos-mojave-support-v2
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --prefix=<installation_path> --enable-only64bit
```

Edit coregrind/Makefile, change this:

```
am__append_19 = \
/usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs \
    /usr/include/mach/task.defs \
    /usr/include/mach/thread_act.defs \
    /usr/include/mach/vm_map.defs
```

to

```
    am__append_19 = \
<PATH TO OSX SDK>/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs \
    <PATH TO OSX SDK>/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/task.defs \
    <PATH TO OSX SDK>/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/thread_act.defs \
    <PATH TO OSX SDK>/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/mach/vm_map.defs
```

Then run

```
$ make
$ make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow alex.m's answer to get valgrind, but if you'r using it on a `int main() { return 0; }` program, you'll get many weird errors, and non-existing allocs / free.

To 'hide' these annoying errors, you can follow theses steps (it's more a workaround than a real fix) (based on [this wiki page](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto) and some research in Valgrind's source code):

- First, create and compile a `int main() { return 0; }` program.
- Execute the following command (to create file containing error suppression):

`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --error-limit=no --gen-supressions=all --log-file=$YOUR_LOG$ $YOUR_BINARY$`

- Using [this gawk script](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Parse_valgrind_suppressions.sh), create the `.supp` valgrind file:

`cat ./$YOUR_LOG$ | ./$YOUR_SCRIPT_FILE$ > minimal.supp`

- Copy and Past `minimal.supp` content at the end of `$YOUR_VALGRIND_INSTALLATION_PATH$/lib/valgrind/default.supp` file

And you are done! Weird and nonexistent errors will be ignored.
If you also want's to remove the non-existing `alloc`s, `free`s etc, you can directly edit Valgrind's source code. Or just use `heapusage` for leak-tracking

Answer (score 0):

(works on mojave 10.14.6)

```
brew install --HEAD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sowson/valgrind/master/valgrind.rb
```