# Valgrind Install Fails MacOS Mojave

Tags: memory-management, homebrew, valgrind

I keep seeing mixed results for Valgrind's status on MacOS Mojave. [Some responses](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/23536) say to use the head url change workaround ( & `brew install --HEAD valgrind`), but this did not work as I still get:

```
-bash: valgrind: command not found
```

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732036/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-mojave10-14-with-homebrew) say it's just not compatible at all with OS Mojave.

Valgrind is a mandatory spec for my C project. How do I go about this?

Comment: There are various options — none of them as helpful as you'd like. One is to get a VM (VMWare Fusion or alternatives to suit — Docker, …) and install a Linux VM with development system and Valgrind. This works. I've got a Valgrind that was built on High Sierra that still sort of runs on Mojave. I need to do some work on the suppressions; there are a lot of new ones that should be handled. It seems to work (but I've not stressed it hard). Whether you can compile a new version is open to debate — I had a go, but it requires at new version of at least one file and I didn't finish (lack of time).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Hi, Jonathan! What do you mean? You installed Valgrind on macOS HighSierra and after updating to Mojave it is working, right?

Comment: I built Valgrind on High Sierra, and it worked there fine.  I since upgraded the machine to Mojave.  The old Valgrind still hobbles along badly on Mojave, but it is barely usable (at best) — and will still only be barely usable if I fix up the suppressions.