# Valgrind not working on MacOS Mojave? Installed with Conda

Tags: c, valgrind, dr-memory

I'm trying to check for memory leaks in a program I wrote in C. I'm running MacOS Mojave. When I run valgrind, I get this error:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./shell.out
valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 520192) failed in UME (load_segment1) with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).
```

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind might not compatible with the newest macOS(10.14 Mojave). 
please check this : [How to install Valgrind on macOS Mojave(10.14) with Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732036/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-mojave10-14-with-homebrew/54818930#54818930)